# List conversion - inplace

Tags: python, arrays, list, in-place

I am trying to convert ['1','2','3','4'] to [1,2,3,4]
I want to make this conversion inplace. Is it possible to do it? If not, what is the optimal solution.

Comment: How large is it? ```lyst[1] = int('1')``` will assign 1 to index 1 of a list.   [```enumerate```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) should help

Comment: around 100 numbers in the array

Comment: It was damn easy!! My bad!

Comment: If you have `100` numbers you really shouldn't be worried about doing things in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with list comprehension like this:

```
l = [int(item) for item in l]
```

Comment: Creates a new list.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) for this kind of tasks. Which creates iterator, what means it is more memory efficient.

```
l = list(map(int, l))
# here I convert it to list, but usually you would just iterate over it
# so you can just do
for item in map(int, l):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty much in-place?

```
In [31]: l = ['1','2','3','4']

In [32]: for i in range(len(l)):
   ....:     l[i] = int(l[i])
   ....:     

In [33]: l
Out[33]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or, you could do it by using `enumerate` which takes an iterable (like a `list`) and returns an `index` and the corresponding value from the beginning till the end:

```
In [84]: l = ['1','2','3','4']

In [85]: for idx, val in enumerate(l):
   ....:     l[idx] = int(val)
   ....:     

In [86]: l
Out[86]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I did the same after thinking for few mins. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You should use `enumerate` for this. It fits the use-case *exactly*.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the whole array fits in memory, you should just be able to step through it, replacing each item as you go:

```
# bigarray is ['1','2','3','4',...];

# loop through bigarray using index i
for i in range(len(bigarray)):
    # coerce bigarray[i] to int in place
    bigarray[i] = int(bigarray[i])

# bigarray is [1,2,3,4,...];
```

good luck!